# Porqué no se muestra la imagen de fondo?

Tags: html, css

Tengo el siguiente código, es bastante sencillo pero no se el porque no me muestra la imagen de fondo especificada en el css.

```
#coach{
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url('../img/foto4coach.png'); 
    background-size: 100%;
}

<div id="coach">
                <h2></h2>
                <div style="margin-top:3rem">
                    <p class="texto_c">     
                    </p>
                    <div style="margin-top:2rem; text-align:center;">
                    <a title="" href="prueba.html"><img src="img/boton4coach.png"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
</div>
```

graciass

Comment: prueba a poner la ruta absoluta

Comment: Es un error de ruta sin duda.

Comment: la ruta esta bien, tengo otros id con la misma url y ruta

Comment: La ruta no está bien (ya sea o la ruta relativa que usas o el nombre de la imagen) para comprobarlo pon de fondo de imagen una ruta absoluta y verás como se muestra.

Comment: El código esta correcto, debe ser un error en la ruta de la imagen. Seria mejor que pusieras la ruta absoluta, aunque si la relativa está bien no debería haber problemas.